# Showing multiple PDF Files in WebBrowser control (Windows Form)

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, webbrowser-control

I’m trying to show PDF files in Windows Form WebBrowser control. I do this by WebBrowser.Navigate() method. It is work when I want show one PDF file, which is not enough for me. I need when a user clicks a button , WebBrowser show another PDF file. What I have to do?

Answer (score 3):

Avoid using `WebBrowser` control just to show a pdf. Try using one of the many free PDF libraries available for .net such as [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/).

This will allow you to draw pdf's on to the `Form` and using `TabControl` you can create tabs programmatically and place a new pdf viewer inside of the tab.

You could easily make a 2 different files PDF viewer (side by side or top and bottom) by using the PDFSharp. Or you can use the ActiveX control for Adobe Reader.

Edit: It was my understanding that PDFSharp can render pdf's directly. This can only be done by exporting the page to a Jpeg/Png and then displaying the images. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Thank you for guidance.I'm trying to use PDFSharp.

Answer (score 1):

At your place I'd do tabControl, and foreach tabControl, I'd put a webbroswer inwhich there would be a PDF by Tab.

EDIT : A WebBroswer isn't like internet explorer. Internet Explorer has the "Feature" of having multiple tabs (just like Chrome, etc). The WebBroswer Element is only the content of the tab :)

EDIT2 : After many years into this, I would recommend using a PDF library also. As a prototype usecase it might work, but in real world, we never know how many there will be. the best would probably to: either let the option to the user to open in a competent software i.e. Acrobat Reader where tab is natively used (DC), or use a PDF Library.

Comment: Thank you but I want show another PDF in same window.when user click button I again use Navigate method but old PDF still showing.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Say the user wants to show 10 PDF files the `WebBrowser` control is terrible with memory and your app will shoot up to 300mb memory usage. Why not just use a PDF library?

Answer (score 0):

What i think is that you are facing a very simple navigate issue here. I have worked out a project for you, take a look at it, I hope it will solve your issue.
download [here](http://goo.gl/bCWCo).